# Compare Values in Excel Sheet1 to Values in Sheet2

Tags: vba, excel

I have an Excel spreadsheet in which I have 2 worksheets. In the first worksheet in Column A I have a Store Names. The second worksheet is a subset of worksheet 1 and also has Store Names, however, they are in Column B of worksheet 2. I need to compare every Store Name (column A) in worksheet 1 to every Store Name (column B) in worksheet 2 and extract where the 2 intersect (have the same Store Names). So far, I have done this in VB with the following:

```
Sub RunMe()
Dim lRow, x As Long

Sheets("Sheet1").Select
lRow = Range("A2").End(xlDown).Row

For Each cell In Range("B2:B" & lRow)
    x = 2
    Do
        If cell.Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(x, "A").Value Then
            cell.EntireRow.Copy Sheets("Sheet3").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
        End If
        x = x + 1
    Loop Until IsEmpty(Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(x, "A"))
Next

End Sub
```

How can I modify the code above to compare EVERY Store Name (Column A) of Worksheet 1 to EVERY Store Name (Column B) of Worksheet 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
Sub RunMe()
    Dim cell1 As Range, cell2 As Range
    Dim rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range

    Set rng1 = GetRange("Sheet1",1)
    Set rng2 = GetRange("Sheet2",2)

    For Each cell2 In rng2
        For Each cell1 In rng1
            If cell1.Value = cell2.Value Then
                cell2.EntireRow.Copy Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
            End If
        Next
    Next
End Sub

Function GetRange(shtName As String, colIndex as Long) As Range
    With Worksheets(shtName)
        Set GetRange = .Range(.Cells(2, colIndex), .Cells(.Rows.Count, colIndex).End(xlUp))
    End With
End Function
```

Comment: This solution does not appear to work. It does not appear to take into account that WorkSheet2 has the Store Names starting in column B2. I modified the solution and still did not copy the data to Worksheet3.

Comment: @dionysus, did you get through it?

Comment: I tried your code suggestion, however, it does not appear that any values are being copied to WorkSheet3. Any clue as to why?

Comment: step through it (press F8 once your cursor is in any statement of RunMe() sub) and query relevant variables via Immediate Window (e.g.: "? Rng1.Address" and press return) to see what's going on)

Comment: Thanks. I went through this process and it makes it to the portion of the code where the values are to be copied to WorkSheet3. The problem is that when I check WorkSheet3, nothing appears to have been copied.

Comment: Made the following changes:  Sub RunMe()
    Dim cell1 As Range, cell2 As Range
    Dim rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range
    Dim cellRow As Integer
    cellRow = 0

    Set rng1 = GetRange("Sheet1", 1)
    Set rng2 = GetRange("Sheet2", 2)

    For Each cell1 In rng1
        For Each cell2 In rng2
            If cell1.Value = cell2.Value Then
                cellRow = cellRow + 1
                cell1.EntireRow.Copy Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("A" & cellRow).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
            End If
        Next
    Next
End Sub